# add <div> around/after <input> in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple input slider in pure javascript (no jQuery). It works perfectly except for one little flaw: I need to call it in the html as

```
<div id="test0" data-options="A;B;C;D;E" class="myslider"></div>
```

instead of the more natural

```
<input type="hidden" class="myslider" data-options="A;B;C;D;E" id="test0">
```

The reason for that is that I depend on  `document.getElementById(name).innerHTML=...` to add the necessary markup to it. So my question is: what can we do to replace, append, modify, replace... html text around an `<input>`? The `innerHTML` seems not to work, and I fail to find an alternative.

Comment: In your code you have `var n = parseInt(value); return n == null ...` For what value of `value` will `parseInt(value) == null` be true? The way I read ECMA-262, [parseInt](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) only returns either an integer or `NaN`.

Comment: Good point, I was being overly covering there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `<div>`, insert `<div>`, change `input`'s `id`?

```
var input = document.getElementById('test0');

var slider = document.createElement('div');
slider.id = input.id;
slider.className = 'myslider';
slider.dataset.options = input.dataset.options;

input.id = null;
input.parentNode.insertBefore(slider, input);
```

Now you can change `slider` to your heart's content. I'd recommend checking out the DOM API instead of throwing HTML into things, though. HTML is messy.

Comment: `A.parentNode.insertBefore(B,A);`, nice, I didn't know that. Works like a charm, thanks!